# What is equivalent of Android i18n plural in django which support zero, one, two, few, many, other?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, internationalization, django-i18n

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

I was found function in django but it not support other languages than English and similar - how to deal with it?

```
def ngettext(singular, plural, number):
    return real_ngettext(singular, plural, number)
```

---

In Android is wider support for language - how to get same in django:

**zero**    When the language requires special treatment of the number 0 (as in Arabic).

**one** When the language requires special treatment of numbers like one (as with the number 1 in English and most other languages; in Russian, any number ending in 1 but not ending in 11 is in this class).

**two** When the language requires special treatment of numbers like two (as with 2 in Welsh, or 102 in Slovenian).

**few** When the language requires special treatment of "small" numbers (as with 2, 3, and 4 in Czech; or numbers ending 2, 3, or 4 but not 12, 13, or 14 in Polish).

**many**    When the language requires special treatment of "large" numbers (as with numbers ending 11-99 in Maltese).

**other**   When the language does not require special treatment of the given quantity (as with all numbers in Chinese, or 42 in English).

I could write custom function but it will make django extraction scripts little useless. What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think GNU gettext which is a basement of the django i18n implementation supports your use cases. Search for `Plural-Forms` in [GNU gettext doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/gettext_150.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be semi-off-topic... I wrote a function for AWK script for Russian language number endings (maybe it will be useful for someone, who cat explore it, and remake it for hi's favorite language):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function rne(rusnum,raz,dva,mnogo){ # Russian Number Endings (rusnum=number; raz -- ending for 1, 21, 101, etc; dva -- 2-4, 22-24, 102-104...; mnogo -- 0, 5-20, 25-30, 95-100...)
 rusnum_tmp[1]=substr(rusnum,length(rusnum),1) #getting units
 rusnum_tmp[2]=substr(rusnum,length(rusnum)-1,1) #getting tens
 rusnum_tmp[1]=rusnum_tmp[1]/1 #converting string to number
 rusnum_tmp[2]=rusnum_tmp[2]/1
 if(rusnum_tmp[1]==1&&(rusnum_tmp[2]!=1||length(rusnum)==1)){
  outrusend=raz
 }else{
  if(rusnum_tmp[1]<=4&&rusnum_tmp[1]>=2&&rusnum_tmp[2]!=1){outrusend=dva}else{outrusend=mnogo}
 }
 return outrusend;
}
```